# Flink : WordCount example throws ClassNotFoundException

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, apache-flink

I'm currently trying to embed Flink in a Play Framework project. But when I try to execute the WordCount example from Flink documentation I get this error:

```
play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[JobExecutionException: Cannot initialize task 'DataSink (collect())': Deserializing the OutputFormat (org.apache.flink.api.java.Utils$CollectHelper@1f158fd6) failed: Could not read the user code wrapper: io.fabrick.aperture.doctor.stream.WordCount$$anon$2$$anon$1]]
    at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:265) ~[play_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:191) ~[play_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:179) [play_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at play.api.DefaultGlobal$.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:212) [play_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at play.api.http.GlobalSettingsHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:94) [play_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$9$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:158) [play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$9$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:155) [play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.util.Failure$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Try.scala:216) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Cannot initialize task 'DataSink (collect())': Deserializing the OutputFormat (org.apache.flink.api.java.Utils$CollectHelper@1f158fd6) failed: Could not read the user code wrapper: io.fabrick.aperture.doctor.stream.WordCount$$anon$2$$anon$1
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$org$apache$flink$runtime$jobmanager$JobManager$$submitJob$7.apply(JobManager.scala:1012) ~[flink-runtime_2.11-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$org$apache$flink$runtime$jobmanager$JobManager$$submitJob$7.apply(JobManager.scala:996) ~[flink-runtime_2.11-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:742) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1194) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager.org$apache$flink$runtime$jobmanager$JobManager$$submitJob(JobManager.scala:996) ~[flink-runtime_2.11-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1.applyOrElse(JobManager.scala:380) ~[flink-runtime_2.11-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.LeaderSessionMessageFilter$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(LeaderSessionMessageFilter.scala:36) ~[flink-runtime_2.11-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Deserializing the OutputFormat (org.apache.flink.api.java.Utils$CollectHelper@1f158fd6) failed: Could not read the user code wrapper: io.fabrick.aperture.doctor.stream.WordCount$$anon$2$$anon$1
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobgraph.OutputFormatVertex.initializeOnMaster(OutputFormatVertex.java:63) ~[flink-runtime_2.11-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$org$apache$flink$runtime$jobmanager$JobManager$$submitJob$7.apply(JobManager.scala:1008) ~[flink-runtime_2.11-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$org$apache$flink$runtime$jobmanager$JobManager$$submitJob$7.apply(JobManager.scala:996) ~[flink-runtime_2.11-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:742) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1194) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager.org$apache$flink$runtime$jobmanager$JobManager$$submitJob(JobManager.scala:996) ~[flink-runtime_2.11-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1.applyOrElse(JobManager.scala:380) ~[flink-runtime_2.11-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.util.CorruptConfigurationException: Could not read the user code wrapper: io.fabrick.aperture.doctor.stream.WordCount$$anon$2$$anon$1
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.util.TaskConfig.getStubWrapper(TaskConfig.java:284) ~[flink-runtime_2.11-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobgraph.OutputFormatVertex.initializeOnMaster(OutputFormatVertex.java:60) ~[flink-runtime_2.11-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$org$apache$flink$runtime$jobmanager$JobManager$$submitJob$7.apply(JobManager.scala:1008) ~[flink-runtime_2.11-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$org$apache$flink$runtime$jobmanager$JobManager$$submitJob$7.apply(JobManager.scala:996) ~[flink-runtime_2.11-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:742) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1194) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager.org$apache$flink$runtime$jobmanager$JobManager$$submitJob(JobManager.scala:996) ~[flink-runtime_2.11-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1.applyOrElse(JobManager.scala:380) ~[flink-runtime_2.11-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.fabrick.aperture.doctor.stream.WordCount$$anon$2$$anon$1
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil$ClassLoaderObjectInputStream.resolveClass(InstantiationUtil.java:64) ~[flink-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1613) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
```

I launch my project directly from IntelliJ (I don't know if this can be the root cause).

Here comes the code executed :

```
object WordCount {

  def test():Unit = {

    // set up the execution environment
    val test = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

    // get input data
    val text = test.fromElements("To be, or not to be,--that is the question:--",
      "Whether 'tis nobler in the mind to suffer", "The slings and arrows of outrageous fortune",
      "Or to take arms against a sea of troubles,")

    val counts = text.flatMap { _.toLowerCase.split("\\W+") }
      .map { (_, 1) }
      .groupBy(0)
      .sum(1)

    // emit result
    counts.print()

    // execute program
    test.execute("WordCount Example")
  }
}
```

Any help is welcome, thank you all !

Edit : Just to add the dependency list :

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-scala" % "1.0.0",
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-clients" % "1.0.0",
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-streaming-scala" % "1.0.0",
)
```

Comment: Can you show your build.sbt dependencies? It seems it can't find a class, so you may be missing some jar/dependency...

Comment: Hello Salem, I just edit my post to add the dependencies.

Comment: As far as I recall, Flink build assumes that some dependencies (for hadoop I think) are marked as 'provided', i.e. sbt won't pull them in and expects you to provide them in your application. You could try to poke in pom.xlm in Flink to find what needs to be provided or alternatively take dependency on fat jar (that has all dependencies packed in).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have deployed your jar to all Flink instances (jobmanager + all taskmanager nodes).